# How can I put a block inside a tag to change the class?

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

This is what I have on the base class

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#" th:href="@{/home}">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li class="active">
        <a href="#" th:href="@{/page}">My Page</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The `class="active"` is a class that makes the side navigation bar highlight the appropriate tab that the user is on. I have done this manually for each page but I know with `Thymeleaf` you can have a base class and just tag the things you want changed on the page and replace them with new content.

This is what I had so far...
`base.html`

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#" th:href="@{/home}">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li th:include="this :: active">
        <a href="#" th:href="@{/page}">My Page</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`page.html`

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav" th:fragment="active">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#" th:href="@{/page}">My Page</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But my question is.. Is it possible for me to just replace the word `active` for `class="active"` in the `<li>` tag?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this and tell if this worked for you

base class

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#" th:href="@{/home}">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/page' ? 'active':''}">
        <a href="#" th:href="@{/page}">My Page</a>
    </li>
    <li th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/otherpage' ? 'active':''}">
        <a href="#" th:href="@{/otherpage}">My Other Page</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and in page.html delete the active class

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav" th:fragment="active">
        <a href="#" th:href="@{/page}">My Page</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply :) That didn't work no. You can click on the tab, but it does not highlight

Comment: in the generated html what is the actual html for this <li th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/page' ? 'active':''}">
        <a href="#" th:href="@{/page}">My Page</a>
    </li>

Comment: Also, when you go to page 'page' what is the request URI that is called?

Comment: Oh wait sorry my bad... you see for the purpose of the question here I changed the names of the pages. I forgot to change  `/page`, it works ... thank you so much

Comment: Ok, I am glad to hear that!